# How to get App service environment ID to use in App service plan in terraform

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-service-envrmnt, app-service-environment

Can someone help in deploying App service environment using ARM template.

```js
data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name = "${var.rg_name}"
}

resource "azurerm_template_deployment" "deploy" {
  name                = "${var.deployment_name}"
  resource_group_name = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"

  template_body = <<DEPLOY
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "aseName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "subscriptionId": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "vnetName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "subnetName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "vnetId": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "VNetResourceGroupName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "vnetAddress": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "subnetAddress": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "subnetRouteTableName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "subnetNSGName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "ilbMode": {
            "type": "int"
        },
        "subnetId": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
            "name": "existingVnetTemplate",
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "resourceGroup": "[parameters('VNetResourceGroupName')]",
            "subscriptionId": "[parameters('subscriptionId')]",
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "template": {
                    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {},
                    "variables": {},
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
                            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
                            "name": "[concat(parameters('vnetName'), '/', parameters('subnetName'))]",
                            "properties": {
                                "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnetAddress')]",
                                "networkSecurityGroup": {
                                    "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('subnetNSGName'))]"
                                },
                                "routeTable": {
                                    "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/routeTables', parameters('subnetRouteTableName'))]"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "parameters": {}
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/', parameters('subnetNSGName'))]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/routeTables/', parameters('subnetRouteTableName'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2019-02-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments",
            "name": "[parameters('aseName')]",
            "kind": "ASEV2",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "name": "[parameters('aseName')]",
                "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                "InternalLoadBalancingMode": "[parameters('ilbMode')]",
                "virtualNetwork": {
                    "Id": "[parameters('subnetId')]"
                }
            },
            "tags": {},
            "dependsOn": [
                "['existingVnetTemplate']"
            ]
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables",
            "name": "[parameters('subnetRouteTableName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "tags": {
                "displayName": "UDR - Subnet"
            },
            "properties": {
                "routes": [
                    {
                        "name": "abdc-route",
                        "properties": {
                            "addressPrefix": "0.0.0.0/0",
                            "nextHopType": "Internet"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2017-06-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
            "name": "[parameters('subnetNSGName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "tags": {
                "displayName": "NSG - Subnet"
            },
            "properties": {
                "securityRules": [
                    {
                        "name": "Inbound-management",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "Used to manage ASE from public VIP",
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "454-455",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 100,
                            "direction": "Inbound"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Inbound-load-balancer-keep-alive",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "Allow communication to ASE from Load Balancer",
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "16001",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "AzureLoadBalancer",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 105,
                            "direction": "Inbound"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "ASE-internal-inbound",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "ASE-internal-inbound",
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "*",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "[parameters('subnetAddress')]",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 110,
                            "direction": "Inbound"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Inbound-HTTP",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "Allow HTTP",
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "80",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 120,
                            "direction": "Inbound"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Inbound-HTTPS",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "Allow HTTPS",
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "443",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 130,
                            "direction": "Inbound"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Inbound-FTP",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "Allow FTP over port 21",
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "21",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 140,
                            "direction": "Inbound"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Inbound-FTPS",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "Allow FTPS",
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "990",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 150,
                            "direction": "Inbound"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Inbound-FTP-Data",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "RDP",
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "10001-10020",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 160,
                            "direction": "Inbound"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Inbound-Remote-Debugging",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "Visual Studio remote debugging",
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "4016-4022",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 170,
                            "direction": "Inbound"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Outbound-443",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "Azure Storage blob",
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "443",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 100,
                            "direction": "Outbound"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Outbound-DB",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "Database",
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "1433",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "Sql",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 110,
                            "direction": "Outbound"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Outbound-DNS",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "DNS",
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "53",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 120,
                            "direction": "Outbound"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "ASE-internal-outbound",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "Azure Storage queue",
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "*",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "[parameters('subnetAddress')]",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 130,
                            "direction": "Outbound"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Outbound-80",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "Outbound 80",
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "80",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 140,
                            "direction": "Outbound"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "ASE-to-VNET",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "ASE to VNET",
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "*",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "[parameters('vnetAddress')]",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 150,
                            "direction": "Outbound"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Outbound-NTP",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "Clock",
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "123",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 160,
                            "direction": "Outbound"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
DEPLOY
  parameters = {
    "location"      = "${var.location}"
    "aseName" = "${var.aseName}"
    "subscriptionId" = "${var.subscriptionId}"
    "vnetName" = "${var.vnetName}"
    "subnetName" = "${var.subnetName}"
    "vnetId" = "${var.vnetId}"
    "VNetResourceGroupName" = "${var.VNetResourceGroupName}"
    "vnetAddress" = "${var.vnetAddress}"
    "subnetAddress" = "${var.subnetAddress}"
    "subnetRouteTableName" = "${var.subnetRouteTableName}"
    "subnetNSGName" = "${var.subnetNSGName}"
    "ilbMode" = "3"
    "subnetId" = "${var.subnetId}" 
  }

  deployment_mode = "Incremental"
}

"outputs": {
  "app_service_evironment_id": {
    "type": "string",
"value": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments', parameters('aseName'))]",
}
}
```

How do i get the ID of App service environment(Hostingenvironment) in this template so that i am able to output it in terraform and use it in App service plan parameter (app_service_environment_id). This is to deploy the app service in a private network.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/app_service_plan.html#app_service_environment_id

I tried deploying App service environment from azure portal and mentioning its ID in the format "/subscription/xxxx-xxx-xx-xxxx-xxx/Microsoft.web/Hostingenvironment/" which returned a 404.

eg: app_service_environment_id = "/subscription/xxxx-xxx-xx-xxxx-xxx/Microsoft.web/Hostingenvironment/xxxxxxx"

Any help

Comment: Maybe you can provide all your terraform code and the template you used to create the App service environment, it's better if you can successfully deploy the template.

Comment: Hi Charles, i have added the complete template. I am trying to get the ID of the ASE so i can refer it in my App service plan "ASE ID" so as to deploy my app services in private network.Thanks

Comment: Any more updates for the question? Does it solve your problem? If yes, please accept it.

Comment: Hi Alex, dint try it yet, will try today and update you. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I'm not Alex. But I will wait for the result.

Comment: In fact both your answers were right. That helped. I was not including the output in the template section. Thanks both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake you made is that you need to put the output inside the template code, not the Terraform code. So your Terraform code should like this:

```js
data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name = "${var.rg_name}"
}

resource "azurerm_template_deployment" "deploy" {
  name                = "${var.deployment_name}"
  resource_group_name = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"

  template_body = <<DEPLOY
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "aseName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "subscriptionId": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "vnetName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "subnetName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "vnetId": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "VNetResourceGroupName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "vnetAddress": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "subnetAddress": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "subnetRouteTableName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "subnetNSGName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "ilbMode": {
            "type": "int"
        },
        "subnetId": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
            "name": "existingVnetTemplate",
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "resourceGroup": "[parameters('VNetResourceGroupName')]",
            "subscriptionId": "[parameters('subscriptionId')]",
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "template": {
                    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {},
                    "variables": {},
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
                            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
                            "name": "[concat(parameters('vnetName'), '/', parameters('subnetName'))]",
                            "properties": {
                                "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnetAddress')]",
                                "networkSecurityGroup": {
                                    "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('subnetNSGName'))]"
                                },
                                "routeTable": {
                                    "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/routeTables', parameters('subnetRouteTableName'))]"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "parameters": {}
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/', parameters('subnetNSGName'))]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/routeTables/', parameters('subnetRouteTableName'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2019-02-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments",
            "name": "[parameters('aseName')]",
            "kind": "ASEV2",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "name": "[parameters('aseName')]",
                "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                "InternalLoadBalancingMode": "[parameters('ilbMode')]",
                "virtualNetwork": {
                    "Id": "[parameters('subnetId')]"
                }
            },
            "tags": {},
            "dependsOn": [
                "['existingVnetTemplate']"
            ]
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables",
            "name": "[parameters('subnetRouteTableName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "tags": {
                "displayName": "UDR - Subnet"
            },
            "properties": {
                "routes": [
                    {
                        "name": "abdc-route",
                        "properties": {
                            "addressPrefix": "0.0.0.0/0",
                            "nextHopType": "Internet"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2017-06-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
            "name": "[parameters('subnetNSGName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "tags": {
                "displayName": "NSG - Subnet"
            },
            "properties": {
                "securityRules": [
                    {
                        "name": "Inbound-management",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "Used to manage ASE from public VIP",
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "454-455",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 100,
                            "direction": "Inbound"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Inbound-load-balancer-keep-alive",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "Allow communication to ASE from Load Balancer",
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "16001",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "AzureLoadBalancer",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 105,
                            "direction": "Inbound"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "ASE-internal-inbound",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "ASE-internal-inbound",
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "*",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "[parameters('subnetAddress')]",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 110,
                            "direction": "Inbound"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Inbound-HTTP",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "Allow HTTP",
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "80",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 120,
                            "direction": "Inbound"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Inbound-HTTPS",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "Allow HTTPS",
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "443",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 130,
                            "direction": "Inbound"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Inbound-FTP",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "Allow FTP over port 21",
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "21",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 140,
                            "direction": "Inbound"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Inbound-FTPS",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "Allow FTPS",
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "990",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 150,
                            "direction": "Inbound"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Inbound-FTP-Data",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "RDP",
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "10001-10020",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 160,
                            "direction": "Inbound"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Inbound-Remote-Debugging",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "Visual Studio remote debugging",
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "4016-4022",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 170,
                            "direction": "Inbound"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Outbound-443",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "Azure Storage blob",
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "443",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 100,
                            "direction": "Outbound"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Outbound-DB",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "Database",
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "1433",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "Sql",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 110,
                            "direction": "Outbound"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Outbound-DNS",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "DNS",
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "53",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 120,
                            "direction": "Outbound"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "ASE-internal-outbound",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "Azure Storage queue",
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "*",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "[parameters('subnetAddress')]",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 130,
                            "direction": "Outbound"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Outbound-80",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "Outbound 80",
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "80",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 140,
                            "direction": "Outbound"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "ASE-to-VNET",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "ASE to VNET",
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "*",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "[parameters('vnetAddress')]",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 150,
                            "direction": "Outbound"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Outbound-NTP",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "Clock",
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "123",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 160,
                            "direction": "Outbound"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
      "app_service_evironment_id": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments', parameters('aseName'))]"
    }
  }
}
DEPLOY
  parameters = {
    "location"      = "${var.location}"
    "aseName" = "${var.aseName}"
    "subscriptionId" = "${var.subscriptionId}"
    "vnetName" = "${var.vnetName}"
    "subnetName" = "${var.subnetName}"
    "vnetId" = "${var.vnetId}"
    "VNetResourceGroupName" = "${var.VNetResourceGroupName}"
    "vnetAddress" = "${var.vnetAddress}"
    "subnetAddress" = "${var.subnetAddress}"
    "subnetRouteTableName" = "${var.subnetRouteTableName}"
    "subnetNSGName" = "${var.subnetNSGName}"
    "ilbMode" = "3"
    "subnetId" = "${var.subnetId}" 
  }

  deployment_mode = "Incremental"
}

outputs "app_service_evironment_id" {
    value = "${azurerm_template_deployment.outputs["app_service_evironment_id"]}"
}
```

Or the outputs of the Terraform also can be in the format like this:

```
outputs "app_service_evironment_id" {
        value = "${lookup(azurerm_template_deployment.app_service_evironment_id.outputs, "app_service_evironment_id")}"
    }
```

The outputs of the Terraform only to show you how to use the output in template deployment. So you can also quote it in the service plan like this:

```
resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example" {
  ...
  app_service_environment_id = "${lookup(azurerm_template_deployment.app_service_evironment_id.outputs, "app_service_evironment_id")}"
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The resourceId of an app service environment includes the `resource group`.

```
/subscriptions/xxxx-xxx-xx-xxxx-xxx/resourceGroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments/xxxx
```

If you want to combine the ARM template with your terraform file, there is probably already an answer for this:
[ARM Return App Service Environment ID to use in Terraform Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56278126/arm-return-app-service-environment-id-to-use-in-terraform-script)

> ```
> "outputs": {
>   "app_service_evironment_id": {
>     "type": "string",
>     "value": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments', parameters('ilbase_name'))]"
>   }
> }
> ...
> azurerm_app_service_plan.test.app_service_environment_id = azurerm_template_deployment.ase.outputs["app_service_evironment_id"]
> ```

Comment: Thanks Alex. But i am unable to output the ASE id. I am encountering errors and not able to run the template.